# i want to get the frequency of a data in a column using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i tried using dictionary but it only counts the repetition but i want to know the exact frequency of all datas in a column
what ive used is

```
Sub countThings()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long
Dim items As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ActiveSheet

lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Set items = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For x = 2 To lastrow
If Not items.exists(ws.Range("B" & x).Value) Then
items.Add ws.Range("B" & x).Value, 1
ws.Range("C" & x).Value = items(ws.Range("B" & x).Value)
Else
items(ws.Range("B" & x).Value) = items(ws.Range("B" & x).Value) + 1
ws.Range("C" & x).Value = items(ws.Range("B" & x).Value)
End If
Next x
items.RemoveAll

End Sub
```

and this gives me
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhp5g.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhp5g.png][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhp5g.png%5D%5B1%5D)
[image]

but what i need is

[image]
[[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYOFu.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYOFu.png][4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYOFu.png%5D%5B4%5D)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you were after. Please try it.

```
Sub CountThings()

    Dim Ws          As Worksheet
    Dim Items       As Object           ' Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Arr         As Variant          ' values in column B
    Dim R           As Long             ' loop couner: Rows
    Dim Key         As Variant          ' loop counter: dictionary keys
    
    Set Items = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet                ' better: define tab by name
    With Ws
        ' reading from the sheet is slow
        ' therefore read all items at once
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
        ' this is a 1-based 2-D array, like Arr([Rows], [Column])
        ' where column is always 1 because there's only 1 column
    End With
        
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        If Items.Exists(Trim(Arr(R, 1))) Then
            Items(Trim(Arr(R, 1))) = Items(Trim(Arr(R, 1))) + 1
        Else
            Items.Add Trim(Arr(R, 1)), 1
        End If
    Next R
    
    ReDim Arr(1 To Items.Count, 1 To 2)
    R = 0
    For Each Key In Items.keys
        R = R + 1
        Arr(R, 1) = Key
        Arr(R, 2) = Items(Key)
    Next Key
    
    ' specify the top left cell of the target range
    Ws.Cells(2, "C").Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub
```

You need not Trim the Keys if you are sure that there can't be any stray leading or trailing blanks.

Your second picture doesn't need VBA. It can be produce by this formula, entered in C2 and copied down.

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$13,$B2)
```

In fact, you can even do the job of my above code without VBA. Enter this formula in G2 of your sheet as an array formula (confirmed with CTL + SHIFT + ENTER if you don't have Excel 365), and the other one in H. Then copy both formulas down.

```
[G2] =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$13, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($G$1:G1, $B$2:$B$13), 0)), "")
[H2] =IF($G2<>"",COUNTIF($B$2:$B$13,$G2),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values to column C after you have finished counting and therefore, need another loop:

```vb
Sub countThings()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long
    Dim items As Object
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set items = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If Not items.exists(ws.Range("B" & x).Value) Then
            items.Add ws.Range("B" & x).Value, 1
        Else
            items(ws.Range("B" & x).Value) = items(ws.Range("B" & x).Value) + 1
        End If
    Next x
    
    For x = 2 To lastrow
        ws.Range("C" & x).Value = items(ws.Range("B" & x).Value)
    Next x

    items.RemoveAll
    Set items = Nothing

End Sub
```

A simpler way to achieve what you want is to let excel do the counting for you like this:

```vb
Sub countThings2()
    Dim sDataAddress As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        sDataAddress = "$B$2:$B$" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        
        With .Range(sDataAddress).Offset(0, 1)
            .Formula2 = "=COUNTIF(" & sDataAddress & ",B2)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With   
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i use table and 2 functions. not simple way but works :)

```
Sub Fx()
Dim str_Tab() As String, str_Text As String, str_Result As String
Dim int_Counter As Integer, int_TabItemCounter As Integer, int_LastRow As Integer
Dim rng_WorkRange As Range

int_LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng_WorkRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & int_LastRow)

For i = 1 To int_LastRow
    str_Text = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)
    If i > 1 Then
        str_Result = IsInArray(str_Text, str_Tab)
        If str_Result = -1 Then
            int_TabItemCounter = UBound(str_Tab) - LBound(str_Tab)
            ReDim str_Tab(int_TabItemCounter)
            str_Tab(int_TabItemCounter) = str_Text
            ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = CountThisItem(rng_WorkRange, str_Text)
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = CountThisItem(rng_WorkRange, str_Text)
        End If  '   If str_Result = -1
    Else    '   If i > 1
        ReDim str_Tab(i)
        str_Tab(i) = str_Text
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = CountThisItem(rng_WorkRange, str_Text)
    End If  '   If i > 1
Next i
End Sub
```

function to check is text in table
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
Dim i As Long
' default return value if value not found in array
IsInArray = -1

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        IsInArray = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

function to count item in range

```
Function CountThisItem(CountingRange As Range, a As String) As Integer
Dim rng_FindRange As Range
Dim LA As String

Set rng_FindRange = CountingRange.Find(a, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not rng_FindRange Is Nothing Then
    LA = rng_FindRange.Address
    CountThisItem = 1
    Do
        Set rng_FindRange = CountingRange.Find(a, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=rng_FindRange)
        If Not rng_FindRange Is Nothing And rng_FindRange.Address <> LA Then CountThisItem = CountThisItem + 1
    Loop While rng_FindRange.Address <> LA
Else
    CountThisItem = 0
End If
End Function
```