# count duplicate value and report number of duplicate in each row with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, count, duplicates

Column A have many ID, there are duplicate value such as cell(A2) ID 300502489400, cell(A3) ID 300502520900, cell(A4) ID 300502520900, cell(A5) ID 300502520900, cell(A6) ID 300502523900, cell(A7) ID 300502520900,

i need to count number of duplicate and report in Column B
result such as
cell(B2) =1, cell(B3) =4, cell(B4) =4, cell(B5) =4, cell(B6) =1, cell(B7) =1,

how can i code VBA in excel?
I think it should loop to bring value in each row compare to all value and count.[image]

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434617/i-want-to-get-the-frequency-of-a-data-in-a-column-using-vba)? You simply need a `COUNTIF` formula. No need for VBA

Comment: You have my detailed answer to your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434617/i-want-to-get-the-frequency-of-a-data-in-a-column-using-vba (using VBA or worksheet functions) plus two others which you may want to check out. Just change column B used there to column A you use in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i want to get the frequency of a data in a column using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434617/i-want-to-get-the-frequency-of-a-data-in-a-column-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function to check range and count duplicate items

```
Function CountThisItem(CountingRange As Range, a As String) As Integer
Dim rng_FindRange As Range
Dim LA As String

Set rng_FindRange = CountingRange.Find(a, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not rng_FindRange Is Nothing Then
    LA = rng_FindRange.Address
    CountThisItem = 1
    Do
        Set rng_FindRange = CountingRange.Find(a, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=rng_FindRange)
        If Not rng_FindRange Is Nothing And rng_FindRange.Address <> LA Then CountThisItem = CountThisItem + 1
    Loop While rng_FindRange.Address <> LA
Else
    CountThisItem = 0
End If
End Function
```

used in sub. function find all items so number of duplicates is- 1

```
Sub FindDuplicates()
Dim int_LastRow As Integer
Dim rng_WorkRange As Range
Dim str_Text As String

int_LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng_WorkRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & int_LastRow)

For i = 1 To int_LastRow
    str_Text = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = CountThisItem(rng_WorkRange, str_Text) - 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for answer but result not correct.
https://app.box.com/s/77ci69xo9cw139r1i81a6qzkf794s54y

Comment: delete -1 from ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) = CountThisItem(rng_WorkRange, str_Text) - 1 for ur case i mean numer in column b is numbers of duplicates. if there is none should be 0